# Wordpress Import step 2 issue

Tags: wordpress, post, import

I need to transfer posts and their featured images from one wordpress website to another.

I generated export xml file -> then tried to import it on another wordpress site.

First step (user transfer) went well. But then it opened www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?import=wordpress&step=2 404 error page (not found).

Could anyone help me with that, why it fails and how to fix it?

I have latest wordpress version

P.S. I used this plugin to export posts with featured images - Export media with selected content

Thanks

Comment: Try to update your plugins. @see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/importing-blog-xml-file-going-to-404/

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't remember but it probably fixed by it self... even though it shown the error, files and everything was transferred

Comment: It's my problem too...